# what code style in react native demo ?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I read react native document , in the ListView Demo , I find this code

```
  _renderRow: function(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number, highlightRow: (sectionID: number, rowID: number) => void)
```

what this code ? es6 ? jsx ? this look like typescript , but why react native official demo use typescript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started):

> Flow checks your code for errors through static type annotations.
>   These types allow you to tell Flow how you want your code to work, and
>   Flow will make sure it does work that way.

Example code:

```
// @flow
function square(n: number): number {
  return n * n;
}

square("2"); // Error!
```

The React Native documentation suggests [testing your code with Flow](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/testing.html#flow).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it comes from the link below, and is a version of JavaScript.

[https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html)
 It is explained here,

[[1]: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html)
from the Tutorial 
"Some of the things in here might not look like JavaScript to you. Don't panic. This is the future.

First of all, ES2015 (also known as ES6) is a set of improvements to JavaScript that is now part of the official standard, but not yet supported by all browsers, so often it isn't used yet in web development.

cheers